# Что делает ~ с переменной в php?

Tags: php

Потихоньку готовлюсь к ZEND 7.1 экзамену. Вот вопрос:

Напишите результат выполнения данного кода

```
<?php
$x = 7;
echo ~$x;
```

Ответ: -8

Почему?

Поиск по документации привел меня к побитовой инверсии, когда ~ делает например из 00010 строку 11101

Но как это связано с X = 7 и почему в результате получается -8?

Ниже дан хороший ответ про перевод `0111` (7 в двоичной системе) в `1000` (8 в двоичной системе), однако ответ не `8`, а `-8`. Почему меняется знак? И почему ответ возвращается в виде числа 10-тичной системы (`-8`), а не `1000` (`-1000`) ?

Comment: А почему бы должно выводиться в двоичной системе?

Comment: @Эникейщик ну раз мы перешли на работу с двоичной системой, почему переменная не стала "двоичной". Например я пишу $a = "a2b3" (строка), а потом echo -$a, у нас $a становится integer и выводится как -2 (т.е. строка преобразовывается в число), так почему тут, десятичное число не преобразовывается в двоичное? Почему тип данных в переменной меняется а система исчисления - нет?

Comment: Потому что ничего никуда не преобразовывается. Никакой тип данных не меняется. ЛЮБОЕ число в компьютере ВСЕГДА представлено в двоичном виде. Хотите получить такое на выводе - форматируйте соответствующим образом.

Comment: @Эникейщик неверное объяснение. Из той же документации "Двоичная запись integer доступна с PHP 5.4.0.". А не "любое число всегда представлено в двоичном виде". Спасибо за потраченное время, разберусь с этим сам.

Comment: @Эникейщик $a = 0x1A; (шестнадцатеричное число, аналог 26 в десятичной) echo ~$a выдаст -27 т.е. как я понимаю число преобразуется сначала в двоичную, там всё как надо сдвинется и ответ вернется в десятичной. Видимо она по умолчанию для всех integer используется или завязана на побитовые преобразования.

Comment: Вы путаете яблоки и груши. Внутри компьютера все числа представлены в двоичной системе. Так вот компьютеры устроены.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, я знаю. Только это никакого отношения к моему вопросу не имеет. Вопрос про то, как php работает с integer.

Comment: Судя по вашим комментариям, не знаете и не понимаете.

Comment: @Эникейщик как скажешь.

Answer (score 4):

7 в двоичной системе 0111

~ $a    Отрицание   Устанавливаются те биты, которые не установлены в $a, и наоборот.

0111 -> превращается в 1000 -> 8

Comment: верно, но ответ -8, а не 8. Ваш ответ похож на правду, осталось только разобраться откуда берется -1000, а не 1000.

Comment: @adudnik.ru

PHP использует метод "2'splement" для рендеринга отрицательных двоичных чисел. Если самый левый бит равен 1, то двоичное число отрицательно, и вы переворачиваете биты и добавляете 1. Если оно равно 0, то оно положительно и вам ничего не нужно делать.

Примеры

1 (16 сс) -> 0001 (2 cc) -> 1110 (инверсия, так как самый левый бит равен 1, значит двоичное число отрицательно, мы его опять переворачиваем, это будет уже -1 и добавляем (т.е. отнимаем) -1) -> на выходе получается -2

Comment: @adudnik.ru

Я возможно коряво перевел информацию, но вот источник на англ, попытался как смог объяснить на примере

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445277/why-negation-of-number-operator-in-php-gives-such-strange-results/17445473

Comment: Дополните свой ответ этими данными и я приму как решение. Ещё интересно почему результат выводится в десятичной, а не двоичной системе, раз уж пошли такие конверсии, но думаю это зависит от системы исчисления начального числа.

Comment: Как уже говорили, самый левый бит отвечает за знак числа. 0 - для положительных, 1 - для отрицательных. В зависимости от разрядности системы число 7 десятичное будет представлено не как 0111, а как 32-разрядное число с ведущим нулём. Это про знак, что же до того, почему результат выдан в десятичных числах... Так ведь и аргумент переданный тильде - побитовому отрицанию тоже был десятичным. $x = 7; - десятичное число? Ну или по крайней мере ничто не запрещает php его считать таковым, значит и результат выводится в той же системе счисления. Хотите двоичные? Пишите $x = 0b0111;

Comment: Вам уже пояснили в комментариях что результат выводится по умолчанию в десятичной системе счисления, как в самой распространенной. Если хотите выводить в двоичной - используйте функции форматирования.

Comment: @Quazimorda вот казалось бы да, но нет. $x = 0b0111; echo $x выдаст 7, а echo ~$x; выдаст -8. Аналогично с другими системами исчисления. Полагаю что переменные как их не задай всегда выводятся в десятичной системе в итоге.

Comment: @u_mulder вы первый, кто это пояснил в комментариях.

Comment: @adudnik.ru, виноват, не стал лично проверять, но вам u_mulder написал, что если нужен результат в двоичном виде, следует использовать функции форматирования. Точнее функцию перевода decbin(). Другой вопрос, что в повседневной жизни мы используем десятичные числа. Казалось бы, на кой вам на экран двоичные выводить. Но вообще, можете ))

Comment: @Quazimorda мне не надо ничего выводить, просто разобраться досконально в том, как и почему оно так работает =)